# How can I make Thunderbird IMAP sync moved messages immediately?

Tags: sync, thunderbird, imap

I have TB connecting to the IMAP interface of an exchange server. I also have my mail synchronised to the machine for off-line use.

When I move a message from the inbox to an archive folder, the message moves as expected under TB, but when I look at the actual mail server directly using another client, the message still exists in the inbox.

The only way I know of forcing a flush of the TB state to the IMAP server is to shutdown TB, which is not a fantastic solution. I have IDLE enabled, but this seems to only provide sync from the server to client for changes at the server (no client to server for changes to the IMAP message state).

Is there any obscure setting that I can twiddle to make the state flush to the server immediately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the mail.imap.expunge_option to enable this behaviour.  Details of the settings can be found in the following link:

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Deleting_messages_in_IMAP_accounts#Misc

The option can be modified in Edit -> Preferences -> Advanced -> Config Editor

Comment: Cool, that seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have an exchange server, normally working with OWA. Mail client is TB 31.2.0
mail.imap.expunge_option;1
On top I had to set: mail.imap.expunge_after_delete;true
With this setting moving between folders is fine now.

Comment: As written, your answer is really hard to understand. See the [help center](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) for guidance on how to improve your answer.